# Primefaces p:datatable export EXCEL more than 65535 rows

Tags: excel, datatable, primefaces, apache-poi, export

I am implementing a p: dataTable with more than 65000 rows. When I try to export it to EXCEL with a `p: dataExporter` it shows me the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (65536) outside
>   allowable range (0..65535)

```
<p:dataTable id="repFiles" var="rep" value="#{reportFilesBean.list}" filteredValue="#{reportFilesBean.listFiltered}"
         paginator="true" rows="20" sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage="Empty result"
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         currentPageReportTemplate="Total: {totalRecords} / Transferred: #{reportFilesBean.countTrans} / Not transferred: #{reportFilesBean.countNotTrans}"
         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50,100" scrollable="true"  style="width: 100%;"  >

    <f:event type="org.primefaces.event.data.PostFilterEvent" listener="#{reportFilesBean.postFilter}" />

    <f:facet name="header">
        Files transfered
    </f:facet>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.period}" filterBy="#{rep.period}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Period" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.period}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.filename}" filterBy="#{rep.filename}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Filename" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.filename}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.date}" filterBy="#{rep.date}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Date" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.date}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<h:commandLink>  
    <p:graphicImage value="/images/icons/excel-icon.png" title="XLS" />  
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="repFiles" fileName="Reporte_Files_Transferred" />  
</h:commandLink>
```

As I researched it is that the EXCEL 2003 format only supports up to 65535 rows. However when I change the p: dataExporter to XLSX format it shows me the following error:

```
<h:commandLink>  
    <p:graphicImage value="/images/icons/excel-icon.png" title="XLS" />  
    <p:dataExporter type="xlsx" target="repFiles" fileName="Reporte_Files_Transferred" />  
</h:commandLink>
```

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

My project is maven type and I am using:
Primefaces 5.3
Primefaces-extensions 4.0
Apache Poi 3.15

Very grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solve the problem. I added the poi-ooxml to the maven dependencies and exported correctly.

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add this as an answer. You can (and are encouraged) to answer you own questions!

Answer (score 1):

Archivo POM add

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score -2):

Increase server heap memory space, it will work. Cpu resources limit

Comment: This will for sure not fix the IllegalArgumentException