# Exporting data in Excel file using primefaces dataExporter is throwing error if data is huge

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi, data-export

Exporting 178574 rows in Excel is throwing error "**Invalid row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)**". Which means it can't export data more that 65535 rows.
We have to export option on so many pages and now we are not getting exactly what to do.
We are using **Primefaces 5.3**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I saw some where to use **poi-ooxml** library from Apache and I tested it by removing **poi** library and adding poi-ooxml but it still producing same result.
Please guide us to get desired result, any help or suggestion would be greatly apreciated

Comment: You need to swap from `HSSFWorkbook` to `XSSFWorkbook` to change from the XLS format to the XLSX one with the larger row limit. However, with no code, it is hard to see what / how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Here, [Primefaces p:datatable export EXCEL more than 65535 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590401/primefaces-pdatatable-export-excel-more-than-65535-rows) you can find another person with the same issue.

He solved the issue adding the poi-ooxml to the maven dependencies and using the type "xlsx" in the dataExporter component.

```
 <dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> 
<version>3.15</version> 
</dependency>
```